# css selectors IE6,7 fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Is there any way to emulate css selector "+" in IE6,7?

```
h1 + h2{margin-top: 10px;}
```

Can't find any solution.

Comment: i thought this is a standard selector and should work at least in IE7, doesn't it? cannot check this right now. By the way, these selectors are called [Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: The `+` selector works in IE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to add classes for IE6:

```
<script>
$('H1 + H2').addClass('h2-after-h1');
<script>

<style>
.h2-after-h1 {margin-top: 10px; }
<style>
```

In IE7, adjacent-sibling combinator (`+`) does work natively with limitation caused by bug related to HTML comments. There is [JavaScript workaround](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/08/ie7-css-first-child-adjacent/) that removes HTML comments as DOM nodes after page is loaded.